# Read shell script result in Google Colab Research Notebook

Tags: python, shell, google-colaboratory

I know how to run a script in the notebook (for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54604995/3768871)). Now the question is how can I read the result of the shell script in python?
For example, we have an `echo "hi"` command, or we call a shell script, and we want to read the printed message on the console in python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done easily! You can put it equal to the name of a variable in your code. For example:

```
result = !echo "hello"
```

`result` is a list of strings, that shows the lines of printed output of the command in the console as of its item.

Moreover, you can put it in a loop like all other python expressions:

```
result = []
for i in range(10):
    echo_result = !echo $i
    result.append(echo_result)

result
>> [['0'], ['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['5'], ['6'], ['7'], ['8'], ['9']]
```

Comment: When I try this, it shows up as a syntax error in the notebook UI (although it seems to work anyway).

Comment: @slashdottir It would be nice to submit a new post about the syntax error. That could be an interesting problem to be tackled.

Comment: I suppose, though after looking around a bit, I saw some github discussion in progress already about fixing it